How to enlarge image and display it at bottom of the page
I created a webpage with a theme of  Image gallery. I have inserted several thumbnails. Now I want that whenever a user click on a thumbnail the image gets larger and is displayed in the bottom space of the page.

Here whenever I click on a thumbnail above, I want that the image is displayed in the encircled part of the page.
Below is my HTML and CSS code.
HTML -
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head style="color: antiquewhite;">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image_gallery.css">
        <title style="color: blue;">Image Gallery</title>
    </head>

    <body class="FullBody">
        <div class="Heading">
            Responsive Image Gallery
        </div>
        <div class = "AllImages">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="1st image">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="2nd image">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="3rd image">
            <img src="4.jpeg" alt="4th image">
            <img src="5.jpg" alt="5th image">
            <img src="6.jpg" alt="6th image">
            <img src="7.jpg" alt="7th image">
            <img src="8.jpg" alt="8th image">
            <img src="9.jpg" alt="9th image">
            <img src="10.jpg" alt="10th image">
        </div>

        <footer class="Footer">
            <span class="FooterRight">Copyright - Harsh Jain</span>
            <span class="FooterLeft">Created - 03/07/2024</span>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>

CSS -
.FullBody
{
    background-image: url('BackgroundImage.jpg');
    background-size: cover ;
}
.Heading
{
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: azure;
    height: 100px;
}
.Footer
{
    height:40px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    align-content: center;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:0px;
}
.FooterLeft
{
    float: left;
}
.FooterRight
{
    float: right;
}
img
{
    height:100px;
    width:9.78%;
    border:2px solid whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 2px;
    float:left;
}
.AllImages
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

I tried searching but got no help all I got was resizing of images on clicking.
One of the link is here.

Resizing an image from such a small source image would not be a great idea. An alternative would be to have both a small image and a large image to begin with and when a user clicks the small image, the large one appears.

You mean something like this?

No it should be like https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/
One of my friend shared this with me just now.



function displayImage(img) {
  var largeImage = document.getElementById("largeImage");
  largeImage.src = img.src;
}
.FullBody {
  background-image: url("BackgroundImage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.Heading {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Arial Narrow Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: xx-large;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: azure;
  height: 100px;
}

.Footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.FooterLeft {
  float: left;
}

.FooterRight {
  float: right;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 9.78%;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.AllImages {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.displayArea {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.displayArea img {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 400px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image_gallery.css" />
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
  </head>

  <body class="FullBody">
    <div class="Heading">Responsive Image Gallery</div>
    <div class="AllImages">
      <img src="1.jpg" alt="1st image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="2.jpg" alt="2nd image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="3.jpg" alt="3rd image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="4.jpg" alt="4th image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="5.jpg" alt="5th image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="6.jpg" alt="6th image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="7.jpg" alt="7th image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="8.jpg" alt="8th image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="9.jpg" alt="9th image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
      <img src="10.png" alt="10th image" onclick="displayImage(this)" />
    </div>
    <div id="displayArea" class="displayArea">
      <!-- The clicked image will be displayed here -->
      <img id="largeImage" src="" alt="Large Image" />
    </div>
    <footer class="Footer">
      <span class="FooterRight">Copyright - Harsh Jain</span>
      <span class="FooterLeft">Created - 03/07/2024</span>
    </footer>
    <script src="image_gallery.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



`// image_gallery.js

function displayImage(img) { var largeImage = document.getElementById("largeImage"); largeImage.src = img.src; }
In this setup:
The displayImage function is called whenever a thumbnail is clicked.
This function sets the src attribute of the large image to the src of the clicked thumbnail, displaying it in the displayArea.

You need to create a container that will handle the image preview, then create a js function that will show the selected image and apply the design.
I made a simple preview image below base on your code, so you can refer to it.


function previewImage(image){
  let previewContainer = document.getElementById('preview')
  let loader = document.getElementById('loader')
    loader.style.display = "block"
  setTimeout(() => {
    loader.style.display = "none"
    previewContainer.style.backgroundImage = `url("${image.src}")`
    previewContainer.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"
    previewContainer.style.backgroundPosition = "center center"
    previewContainer.style.backgroundSize = "cover"
  },500)
}
#preview{
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: auto;
      margin-top: 10px;
      align-items: center;
      display: flex; /* Make #preview a flex container */
      justify-content: center;
}
#loader {
  display:none;
  border: 16px dotted #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.FullBody
{
    /*background-image: url('BackgroundImage.jpg');*/
    background-image: url('https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/single/sand_black_beach_130680_2560x1024.jpg');
    background-size: cover ;
}
.Heading
{
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: azure;
    height: 100px;
}
.Footer
{
    height:40px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    align-content: center;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:0px;
}
.FooterLeft
{
    float: left;
}
.FooterRight
{
    float: right;
}
img
{
    height:100px;
    width:9.60%;
    border:2px solid whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 2px;
    float:left;
}
.AllImages
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom: 110px;
}
<body class="FullBody">
    <div class="Heading">
      Responsive Image Gallery
    </div>
    <div class = "AllImages">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="1st image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="2nd image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="3rd image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="4th image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="5th image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600" alt="6th image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700" alt="7th image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800" alt="8th image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/900" alt="9th image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/110" alt="10th image" onclick="previewImage(this)">
    </div>

    <div id="preview">
      <div id="loader" /> 
    </div>

    <footer class="Footer">
        <span class="FooterRight">Copyright - Harsh Jain</span>
        <span class="FooterLeft">Created - 03/07/2024</span>
    </footer>
</body>



